# Canonical way to compare locales as subsets of each other

Tags: java, locale

Assume I have a locale stored in some config in whatever format, that I can get a `Locale` object from. I then need to check that the current `Locale` is this locale **or a subset of this locale**.

So, what I'm looking for, in essence, is a method `isSubsetLocale(Locale currentLocale, Locale configLocale)` with these properties:

```
isSubsetLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US"), Locale.forLanguageTag("en")) == true;
isSubsetLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US"), Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US")) == true;
isSubsetLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("de-CH"), Locale.forLanguageTag("en")) == false;

// or even
isSubsetLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US"), Locale.forLanguageTag("")) == true;
```

I understand that in 99% of the cases I can just check if the config locale is a prefix of the current locale, but I'm wondering if there's a more idiomatic way to do it.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4647 seems like a good place to look for a standardized way of doing this.

Comment: @AndyTurner I was aware about the existence of this standard, but maybe it actually makes sense to literally look for its implementations.

Comment: @AndyTurner I've looked it up and seems like what I'm looking for is [LanguageRange](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/matching.html). Thanks a lot for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
public static boolean isSubsetLocale(Locale locale1, Locale locale2) {
    String tag1 = locale1.toLanguageTag();
    String tag2 = locale2.toLanguageTag();
    if (tag1.equals("und"))
        tag1 = "";
    if (tag2.equals("und"))
        tag2 = "";
    return tag1.startsWith(tag2);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(isSubsetLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US"), Locale.forLanguageTag("en")));
System.out.println(isSubsetLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US"), Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US")));
System.out.println(isSubsetLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("de-CH"), Locale.forLanguageTag("en")));

System.out.println(isSubsetLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US"), Locale.forLanguageTag("")));
System.out.println(isSubsetLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("en"), Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US")));
```

*Output*

```
true
true
false
true
false
```

Comment: I've mentioned this kind of solution in the Q, but I hoped that there can be some tested (standard library, hopefully) implementation that processes all the edge cases, but if there isn't, I'll have to write something like this indeed

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg What edge cases? If you're asking about edge cases, you should have mentioned that in the question. Show the edge cases you're talking about, in the question.

Comment: nothing specific comes to mind, but, for instance, I wasn't aware of this `"" -> "und"` mapping. Maybe there's something else I must be aware of before implementing this

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg If you list all the locales known to the JVM by language tag in alphabetical order, you'll see that all subsets are prefix-subsets. E.g. run this: `Arrays.stream(Locale.getAvailableLocales()).map(Locale::toLanguageTag).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);` --- The `und` exception is listed in the javadoc of [`forLanguageTag()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#forLanguageTag-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Anyway, there seems to be a built-in functionality for what I'm looking for: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/matching.html

Answer (score -1):

Do you need something more than `locale.getLanguage()` for the comparison? That will give you the prefix for comparison.

```
Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US").getLanguage().equals(Locale.forLanguageTag("en").getLanguage()) //true;
```

Comment: Yep, the config can define locale with different levels of "specifity".

Comment: Fails for the last test case in the question. --- Will also fail for `isSubsetLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("en"), Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US")) == false;`